# Catching yaml parse error

Tags: python-3.x, exception, pyyaml

I can't seem to make my code catch an error:

I have a yaml file with thousands of entries, a few entries are mangled which generates

> ```
> "expected <block end>, but found %r" % token.id, token.start_mark)
> yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
> ```

I'm using Pyyaml with python3

```
with open('yamlfile') as yf:
    allyml = yaml.load_all(yf)
    for listing in allyml:
        try:
            <do stuff>
        #except yaml.parser.ParserError:
        except:
            continue
```

Catching ParserError doesn't work nor just an except.

It works fine till it gets to the mangled yaml entry.

Since PYyaml is throwing a ParserError it must be my try statement...

Comment: `try` and `except` block should be around the line that calls `yaml.load_all`. With that being done, `except yaml.parser.ParserError` should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Do:

```
with open('yamlfile') as yf:
    allyml = yaml.load_all(yf)
    for listing in allyml:
        try:
            <do stuff>
        # Catch all YAMLErrors
        except yaml.YAMLError, exc:
           # print line number of error
           if hasattr(exc, 'problem_mark'):
              mark = exc.problem_mark
              print "Error position: (%s:%s)" % (mark.line+1, mark.column+1)
           continue
```

Rather than:

```
with open('yamlfile') as yf:
    allyml = yaml.load_all(yf)
    for listing in allyml:
        try:
            <do stuff>
        #except yaml.parser.ParserError:
        except:
            continue
```

This will allow you to catch all YAML errors and show the exact line number and column of the error.

Comment: Didn't work. Pyyaml was already telling me the position of the error - I've so many yaml entries though, that I want to simply skip that YAML entry and proceed to the next (rather than fixing up the YAML syntax)